# Constraint items must each be a view or layout guide

Tags: ios, admob

I'm trying to add an Admob Banner at the bottom of my UIViewController:

```
func addBannerViewToView() {
    bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)
    bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-HIDDEN/HIDDEN"
    bannerView.rootViewController = self
    bannerView.delegate = self
    bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(bannerView)
    view.addConstraints(
        [NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                            attribute: .bottom,
                            relatedBy: .equal,
                            toItem: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor,
                            attribute: .top,
                            multiplier: 1,
                            constant: 0),
         NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                            attribute: .centerX,
                            relatedBy: .equal,
                            toItem: view,
                            attribute: .centerX,
                            multiplier: 1,
                            constant: 0)
        ])
    bannerView.load(GADRequest())
}
```

I call this function in `viewDidLoad` but app crashes with:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'NSLayoutConstraint for
>   >: Constraint items must each be a
>   view or layout guide.'

I used an official example https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/banner

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The error is in the first constraint. The correct formulation in iOS 12 is:

```swift
NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                   attribute: .bottom,
                   relatedBy: .equal,
                   toItem: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide,
                   attribute: .bottom,
                   multiplier: 1,
                   constant: 0)
```

It means that the attribute `bottom` of the `bannerView` has to be `equal` to the `bottom` attribute of the `view.safeAreaLayoutGuide`.

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
toItem: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor,
```

With

```
toItem: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide,
```

Or

```
toItem: view,
```

You specify an anchor while as the exception says it must be a usual view or a layoutGuide

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

```
func addBannerViewToView() {
        bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)
        bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-HIDDEN/HIDDEN"
        bannerView.rootViewController = self
        bannerView.delegate = self
        bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(bannerView)
        view.addConstraints(
            [NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                                attribute: .bottom,
                                relatedBy: .equal,
                                toItem: view,
                                attribute: .bottomMargin,
                                multiplier: 1,
                                constant: 0),
             NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                                attribute: .centerX,
                                relatedBy: .equal,
                                toItem: view,
                                attribute: .centerX,
                                multiplier: 1,
                                constant: 0)
            ])
        bannerView.load(GADRequest())
    }
```